# Angular 4 HttpClient - multiple requests

Tags: angular, parallel-processing, angular4-httpclient

My problem is with multiple request to the server by the HttpClient from Angular 4. Simple test code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  startTest(): void {
    this.http.get('/dictionary/1.0/dictionary/pl/events', {
      observe: 'body',
    }).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log('Data', data);
      }
    );
    this.http.get('/dictionary/1.0/dictionary/pl/event_state', {
      observe: 'body'
    }).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log('Data', data);
      }
    );
    this.http.get('/dictionary/1.0/dictionary/pl/event_sentby_categories', {
      observe: 'body'
    }).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log('Data', data);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Result at least one of this request will execute successfully but the rest will fail with the error "JSON parse error: Unexpected EOF".

Looks like subsequent call of the rest service is cancelling currently existing (not finished) calls. I saw examples with the Observable.forkJoin to make a request in parallel they doesn't work as well. I've tried different browser (all on Mac) and effect is the same.

Comment: are you sure you get valid JSON from all of those requests?

Comment: The code you posted is not responsible for this behavior. Probably a server or proxy issue.

Comment: Response is good. When I stack the requests and execute one by one (after getting response from previous) everything is ok. The server part is behaving properly when execute it in parallel from soap-ui. I'll check variants with execution though the proxy.

Comment: Looks like the problem is on the server side - I've written simple node server and the same request went through without any problem

Comment: And indeed the problem was with the LogFilter implemented by my team. The filter has been using private members and since it's singleton it messed up with the request. Live is good, angular is sill good ;)